Online stores don't have to pay for hefty "rental fees associated with the premises" - Alternatives for the words in quotes

Online stores don't have to pay for hefty rental fees associated with the premises.

I'd like to use a noun phrase here, but I think the one I'm using in the sentence above is a bit too long. I'm referring to the fee we need to pay for renting business premises. I was thinking of using business premises rent, but I'm not sure either.

Online stores don't have to rent premises says all that you need.

You pay fees, you don't pay for fees (same for rents etc: you pay for a thing you buy/rent, you pay money/fees/payments). "Online stores don't have to pay hefty rents" is fine.

@StuartF - online stores don't have to pay any rents, hefty or minimal.

I think it's just called rent, and you can contrast online with brick and mortar. For example:

Online stores don't have the high rent that brick and mortar stores do.


Online stores may have to pay warehouse rents, so perhaps you want to say something like this:

Online stores do not have to pay for retail space.

retail space (in American English, perhaps also in BrE) is a standard phrase in the real estate market.
